# calculating the macro/micro average

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

my data is spam/ham data ... and I am trying to calculate the Micro/Macro average using the builtin functions but I am getting the same number exactly. they both gave me: 0.6666666667 ... 
can this be true ? and even if change the data they gave me different number than the one above but with Macreo=Micro !
my calculation is like this:

```
cm= metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
#calculating the FP,FN
TP=cm[1,1]
TN=cm[0,0]
FP=cm[0,1]
FN=cm[1,0]
print cm

#calculating the false positive rate
print "calculating the false positive rate"
print FP,TN,FP
print FP/float(TN+FP)
print "calculating the macro-averaged"
print metrics.average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='macro', sample_weight=None)
print "calculating the macro-averaged"
print metrics.average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro', sample_weight=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro and macro averages are defined for **multi class** problems (or at least sequences). If your data is simple, binary labeled classification (and it seems so) these two objects are **identical**.

Comment: I sorry .. Iam not sure whether it should be really binary labeled classification or I am doing something wrong ! I am classifing ham/spam using collected texts as the features !

Comment: This is exactly simple, binary classification, thus there is no such thing as micro or macro averaging, they both degenerate to "just" regular metric

Comment: I see .. Many thanks for your help .. Cannot thank you enough